# Stream of updates to the largest time window in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From a time-windowed, keyed stream I'd like to get a stream of the largest window seen so far (largest in terms of count of elements).

Currently I have the following code:

```
source
  .keyBy(...)
  .timeWindow(...)
  .fold((DummyKey, 0)) { case ((_, current), key) => (key, current + 1) }
  .keyBy(_ => ())
  .maxBy(1)
```

The result of the `fold` is a stream of `(key, count)` elements - so from this stream, I want to get a stream of updates of the "key with highest count".

I then key by a constant (`keyBy(_ => ())` - as this is a global operation), and use `maxBy` - and this *almost* works: I'm getting a stream of highest counts, but the current highest count is emitted for each element.

I think what I'm looking for is some kind of filter-with-previous value, which would only emit elements when the new value is different from the previous.

Is that possible in Flink currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink does not feature such a filter by default, but it should be rather easy to implement one yourself.

You can do this with a stateful `FlatMap` similar to this one:

```
val source: DataStream[Int] = ???

source
  .keyBy(_: Int => _)
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(10))
  .fold((1, 0)) { case ((_, current), key) => (key, current + 1) }
  // move everything to the same key
  .keyBy(_ => 0) 
  // use stateful flatmap to remember highest count and filter by that
  .flatMapWithState( (in, state: Option[Int]) => 
    // filter condition
    if (in._2 > state.getOrElse(-1)) 
      // emit new value and update max count
      (Seq(in), Some(in._2)) 
    else 
      // emit nothing (empty Seq()) and keep count
      (Seq(), state)
  ).setParallelism(1)
```

If the non-parallel (single threaded) filter operator becomes a bottleneck, you can add parallel pre-filter by adding a `keyBy` with random keys and a stateful filter `FlatMap` with higher parallelism.

Comment: Ah! I had flink 1.0 in the classpath, which didn't include the `flatMapWithState` operation :) Thanks!

Comment: Is the `setParallelism(1)` needed? Won't the parallelism be 1 anyway because of grouping by the same key?

Comment: The grouping is done with a key selector function. To Flink this function is a black box, i.e., does not know that the function returns a constant value. Flink would start several parallel instance, but all data would go to just one. In principle, the function could be analyzed to infer its behavior, but this is not done (yet).

Comment: Ah, so that's just helping out flink - but not essential to get a correct answer. Thanks again :)